# I'm locked out of machine as will not accept password as I shut down while using French keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, password

I cannot get into my Mac Book Pro, I just get the password picture which shakes.

The only different key for the password is a which is `q` on French keyboard but that doesn't unlock either.  I normally work with English keyboard but was using a French keyboard when the machine shut down.

Is there any sequence of keypresses to bypass the password so I can get into the machine?

Comment: but you can get in to the guest account, that does not need password!

Comment: Which french keyboard, Canadian french, Swiss French, French-numerical ?? French ?

Comment: There are other differences on a french keyboard. The main ones are: A and Q are inverted, so are Z and W. Numerics usually are accessed by pressing shift.

Comment: Yes there are other differences, it depends what French keyboard did he switch to before logging out.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could change the password to something "keyboard language neutral" via single-user mode. Quoting from [Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080414140636495)

> 1. Boot into single user mode (press Command-S at power on)
> 2. Type `fsck -fy`
> 3. Type `mount -uw /`
> 4. Type `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist`
> 5. Type `dscl . -passwd /Users/username password`, replacing `username` with the targeted user and `password` with the desired password.
> 6. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Can you access another user account? If so, enter this account, change the keyboard setting then you can retry your account. Something useful to do before logging out is to go to account and group prefs, and tick the box "show Keyboard setting in login window. I happened to me as my cat walked on the keyboard and change it to Dvorak (clever rascal) and this trick save my life.